# Add spatial functions to a geopackage template

Tags: sql, geopackage, odbc

I would like to dump data from my survey software to a geopackage file through an ODBC connection but I need a minimum of spatial functions to execute my requests:
ST_IsEmpty(geom), ST_MinX(geom), ST_MaxX(geom), ST_MinY(geom), ST_MaxY(geom), GeomFromEwkt, St_Multi.

Here's a exemple of my PostGIS request through ODBC:

```
|   INSERT INTO myTab
|   ( name,
|   date_cmp,
|   geom)
|   VALUES
|   ([myPoint],
|   to_timestamp([[myPoint]:DT]),
|   ST_SetSRID(GeomFromEwkt('JS_WKT([myPoint],P3)'),3163)
|   );
```

JS_WKT(component,type) is producing an EWKT.

My gpkg is a template file made by qgis 2.18.17 my software will copy an fill with Insert requests.

My question is a little similar to [geopackage-update-query-generates-an-error-no-such-function-st-isempty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249787/geopackage-update-query-generates-an-error-no-such-function-st-isempty)

Answer (score 3):

**New clue:**

> starting since 4.2.0 loading the dynamic extension on the top of
>   SQLite3 is now based on "mod_spatialite" (a pure extension module, not
>   a classic shared library). You can eventually read more technical
>   details from [here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=mod_spatialite).

After some tests, I found a way to make it work:

- download le lib spatialite-4.3.0a-win-x86.7z from [here](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-x86/) ;
- unzip it in C:\Windows\System32\;
- create a SQLite ODBC source on a geopackage;
- load the extension from a request;

  SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');
- use my spatial request.

  SELECT ST_MinX(geom), ST_MinX(geom), ST_IsEmpty(geom)
  FROM "block";

And it work fine!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a sqlite database cannot have stored spatial functions.

Spatial library are dynamicaly linked to the software opening the database through the loading of extensions.[Spatially enable an SQLite database](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/help/data/databases/spatially-enable-sqlilte.htm)

The the SQLite3 ODBC driver ([sqliteodbc](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/)) I use have an option to load a folder of extensions.
[How to load Spatialite extension via SQLite3 ODBC Driver?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84829/how-to-load-spatialite-extension-via-sqlite3-odbc-driver)

A google group explains it on [Tech Note: SpatiaLite and language connectors
(aka: SQLite's loadable dynamic extensions)](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/EqJAB8FYRdI) for more recent work on this.