# Error updating geopackage layer attribute in Python using sqlite3

Tags: python, geopackage, update

I'm attempting to update an attribute field in a geopackage layer using the Python sqlite3 module, but any attempt at update is giving an error "no such function: ST_IsEmpty".

Is there anything I can do to make the updates work?

Running python-qgis in an OSGeo4W shell (python 3.7):

```
import sqlite3
gpkg = 'addressbaseplus.gpkg'
conn = sqlite3.connect(gpkg)
cur = conn.cursor()
SQL="update os_addressbaseplus_joined set address = 'xxxx' where fid = 22"
cur.execute(SQL)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: ST_IsEmpty
```

Google tells me this error is something to do with spatial indexing, but I'm not going near the geometry column???

Comment: Do you know what software has created your geopackage? It is odd that update of the normal attribute (not geometry) triggers the check of spatial index. Your GeoPackage may contain non-standard triggers.

Comment: The geopackage was created using ogr2ogr on a csv file. The point of using python is to compose the address field based on the content of some 30 other fields.

Comment: Then you should have just the triggers that the standard mandates. See http://www.geopackage.org/spec121/ from "Define Triggers to Maintain Spatial Index Values". Triggers should kick in only when the geometry column is affected. You can feel happy because it works for you now, but if you are curious, you could have a try with finding out why the ST_IsEmpty is required. You should start then from very simple updates.

Answer (score 2):

The final "[Similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343568/updating-geopackage-records-with-r)" led to the answer: I hadn't enabled the spatial extensions to sqlite3

Adding the following resolved the issue

```
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.load_extension("mod_spatialite")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that GeoPackage requires a few functions which do not belong to standard SQLite. They are documented in http://www.geopackage.org/spec121/

> **ST_IsEmpty**(geom Geometry): integer
>
> Returns 1 if geometry value is empty, 0 if not empty, NULL if geometry
> value is NULL
>
> Test if a geometry value corresponds to the empty set
>
> **ST_MinX**(geom Geometry): real
>
> Returns the minimum X value of the bounding envelope of a geometry
>
> Update the spatial index on a geometry column in a feature table
>
> **ST_MaxX**(geom Geometry): real
>
> Returns the maximum Y value of the bounding envelope of a geometry
>
> Update the spatial index on a geometry column in a feature table
>
> **ST_MinY**(geom Geometry): real
>
> Returns the minimum X value of the bounding envelope of a geometry
>
> Update the spatial index on a geometry column in a feature table
>
> **ST_MaxY**(geom Geometry): real
>
> Returns the maximum Y value of the bounding envelope of a geometry
>
> Update the spatial index on a geometry column in a feature table

Obviously loading mod_spatialite gives you those functions but GeoPackage does not require SpatiaLite. Probably there is also some more lightweight way to get just the five mandatory functions.

**EDIT**

There is code in the GDAL GeoPackage sources https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/595f74bf60dff89fc5df53f9f4c3e40fc835e909/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/gpkg/ogrgeopackagedatasource.cpp that creates the functions. If you want to use GeoPackages with your own code without GDAL and without SpatiaLite I guess you should create the functions similarly. The easier way is to open GeoPackages with GDAL, or use mod_spatialite as you already did.